# Nodejs stream is not getting caught in error event listener. I am using npm Imap module and the stream error is not getting caught in error listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, stream, event-listener

```
imap.once('ready', function() {
  openInbox(function(err, box) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var f = imap.seq.fetch('1:3', {
      bodies: 'HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)',
      struct: true
    });
    f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
      console.log('Message #%d', seqno);
      var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
      msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
        var buffer = '';
        stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
          throw new Error('Custom Error');
        });
        stream.once('end', function() {
          console.log(prefix + 'Parsed header: %s', inspect(Imap.parseHeader(buffer)));
        });
      });
      msg.once('attributes', function(attrs) {
        console.log(prefix + 'Attributes: %s', inspect(attrs, false, 8));
      });
      msg.once('end', function() {
        console.log(prefix + 'Finished');
      });
    });
    f.once('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
    });
    f.once('end', function() {
      console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
      imap.end();
    });
  });
});
```

The code is the direct example code of npm imap https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap
So, I am just throwing a custom error from **stream data event**.

Now I want to catch that error for which I tried

```
stream.on('error', function (err) {
    logger.info('Error');
});
```

But this is not catching it. Also, tried try catch block.
How to catch and handle this error